# Anomaly Detection for Categorical Data

Tags: time-series, categorical-data, anomaly-detection

Lets say i have a table which has 10 categorical features for each customer and these features are recorded on a daily grain. This means that  I have 10 categorical time series for each customer.Now I need to find wether there are data quality issue in the table ie I want to create a model for outlier detention.

How do i approach this problem.